# ScrollViewer steals focus

Tags: wpf, focus, scrollviewer

Why in the next XAML clicking on disabled button cause ScrollViewer to steal focus from TextBox? Is it right? What is the workaround?

```
<Window
x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TextBox}">
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox"/>
        <Button IsEnabled="False" Content="Disabled Button"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Setting IsFocusable="False" on ScrollViewer helps. But is it right workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do `IsFocusable="False"` or `IsHitTestable="False"`

Comment: But isn't it take away a possibility to focus on ScrollViewer's ScrollBars buttons? Is it a workaround or is it the right way to strip ScrollViewer focusability?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, this does work, and as far as I can tell, it does not impair the ability to select the ScrollViewer's scrollbar. It just strips away the bubbling effect of child controls going up to the ScrollViewer. There may be underlying problems with using this, but I have not found them yet.